# Elasticsearch: query address with prefix and order

Tags: elasticsearch

I have only single field `"address"`, and want to query using prefixes, where order of my entry is matter (it is needed for autocomplete field).

For example, when i'm searching for `"kerb 4-1"`, i expect to get `{ Kerbi st. 4-1 }` with highest score, and records like `{ Kerbi st. 1-4 }`, `{ Kerbi st. 10-42 }` with lower score.
Is it even possible? If not - what other options do i have?

Right now i was able to search only with prefixes:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "prefix": { "address": { "value": "kerb" } } },
        { "prefix": { "address": { "value": "4" } } },
        { "prefix": { "address": { "value": "1" } } }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 50,
  "from": 0,
  "sort": []
}
```

but getting results where all records with same score

```
{ Kerbi st. 10-42 },
{ Kerbi st. 10-46 },
{ Kerbi st. 10-49 },
{ Kerbi st. 10-4 },
{ Kerbi st. 10-40 },
{ Kerbi st. 10-41 },
{ Kerbi st. 10-43 },
{ Kerbi st. 10-44 },
{ Kerbi st. 10-45 },
{ Kerbi st. 10-47 },
{ Kerbi st. 10-48 },
{ Kerbi st. 4-133 },
{ Kerbi st. 4-140 },
{ Kerbi st. 11-43 },
{ Kerbi st. 12-44 },
{ Kerbi st. 18-41 },
{ Kerbi st. 12-4 },
{ Kerbi st. 12-48 },
{ Kerbi st. 11-47 },
{ Kerbi st. 11-45 },
{ Kerbi st. 4-108 },
{ Kerbi st. 4-137 },
{ Kerbi st. 4-115 },
{ Kerbi st. 4-136 },
{ Kerbi st. 11-42 },
{ Kerbi st. 11-44 },
{ Kerbi st. 4-138 },
{ Kerbi st. 18-40 },
{ Kerbi st. 18-43 },
{ Kerbi st. 12-40 },
{ Kerbi st. 12-41 },
{ Kerbi st. 12-49 },
{ Kerbi st. 18-4 },
{ Kerbi st. 18-42 },
{ Kerbi st. 18-49 },
{ Kerbi st. 18-48 },
{ Kerbi st. 18-46 },
{ Kerbi st. 11-4 },
{ Kerbi st. 11-49 },
{ Kerbi st. 11-48 },
{ Kerbi st. 11-46 },
{ Kerbi st. 11-41 },
{ Kerbi st. 11-40 },
{ Kerbi st. 18-44 },
{ Kerbi st. 18-45 },
{ Kerbi st. 4-131 },
{ Kerbi st. 4-1 },
{ Kerbi st. 4-116 },
{ Kerbi st. 4-125 },
{ Kerbi st. 4-118}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `edge_ngram` filter instead the `prefix` query. Order of entries is matter, therefore use the `match_phrase` query or the `match_phrase_prefix` query

Mapping

```
PUT /addresses
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "address": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "edge_ngrams": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "standard_lowercase_edge_ngram_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "standard_lowercase_edge_ngram_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "edge_ngram_filter"
                    ]
                },
                "standard_lowercase_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "edge_ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 11
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are two analyzers: `standard_lowercase_edge_ngram_analyzer` is for indexing, `standard_lowercase_analyzer` is for searching

Documents

```
PUT /addresses/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"address": "Kerbi st. 4-1"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"address": "Kerbi st. 1-4"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"address": "Kerbi st. 10-42"}
```

Query

```
GET /addresses/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "address.edge_ngrams": {
                "query": "kerb 4-1",
                "analyzer": "standard_lowercase_analyzer", 
                "slop": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "addresses",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 0.37585157,
                "_source" : {
                    "address" : "Kerbi st. 4-1"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "addresses",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "2",
                "_score" : 0.29209036,
                "_source" : {
                    "address" : "Kerbi st. 1-4"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "addresses",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "3",
                "_score" : 0.29209036,
                "_source" : {
                    "address" : "Kerbi st. 10-42"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I use an original solution from [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/378555459_Approach_to_the_Search_for_Addresses_with_Incomplete_Query_Text_in_the_Elasticsearch_Engine)